# Transformation and structuring of Excel file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I ask you to help with the solution of the problem.
I recently started learning Python, and I don't have enough experience to solve it yet.

It is necessary to write a python script that transforms an Excel spreadsheet into a flat view for further work and analytics.

Source table: input ex.xlsx
Example of expected result: out ex.xlsx

I will be very grateful for help!

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhLah.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06TZU.jpg)

Comment: Hopefully you realize that without any explanation at all how you want to transform your data, which columns are important or what calculations are needed to obtain result no one will help you.

Comment: Please post what have you done until now and explain how you want the transformation done. And from my experience you can do a much better job with Excel VB macros

Answer (score 0):

Consider to find out more about pandas dataframe. We can then use pd.read_excel() and pd.read_csv() to read the data into memory and process the data using pandas.